# Please increase searches per minute

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, search

> You can only perform 4 searches within a minute

Just got this message from stackoverflow. I agree that there must be a limit to prevent abuses, but 4 searches/minute seems way too restrictive, it makes search almost useless when trying to refine (IMHO a common pattern in searching)

Comment: I hope you don't mind that I changed this into a [feature-request] to increase the searches per minute.

Comment: If you are forming searches at a rate of one per 15 seconds, you may want to consider thinking a little more about what you're really searching for, and searching less frequently.  Alternately, when you find you have to search at this rate, consider using google.

Comment: @Adam: I disagree... searching in SO should be more precise than googling. Lucene is *fast*, I don't see any reason to limit this to 4 searches per minute.

Comment: Don't forget about the [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com) - endless flexibility.

Comment: Meanwhile, [the limit is effectively gone altogether](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160100/a-new-search-engine-for-stack-exchange).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since [the new search was introduced in December 2012](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160100/a-new-search-engine-for-stack-exchange), there is no real limit for humans anymore.

---

March 2011:

In the next build we'll up this to **6** searches/min, but we may tweak it in either direction depending on how usage goes. It's not a super-cheap operation, so we don't want it to be an abuse point in the system.

Remember: paging doesn't count against this limit. But searches that have no result do count.

And for future searches:

> You can only perform 6 searches within a minute, please wait a minute then try again.

Comment: It seems that sorting counts as a new search too? Like when I know something has been asked recently, and hence I want to sort on "newest", all of my searches count as two...

Comment: It seems that searches that have zero results count too? I quite often hit this message. :-(

Comment: @Arjan - This is correct, it's a server load being sane issue, we may increase it more later...but no matter how many results come back there's still a fair amount of load involved on the IO side at the moment...we're working on this :)

Comment: Thanks, @Nick. As for sorting: I am not sure if clicking "newest" runs a new query? If it does, then maybe it helps if the search remembers the last sort order? Any new search always gets one "relevance" first.

Comment: Could this be increased to 10? I occasionally hit the limit, and it's a tiny bit annoying.

Comment: I don't suppose it would be possible to treat changing through the different tabs or changing pages as part of the original search.  Usually the first thing I do when I perform a search is switch to the votes or newest tab.  That act alone makes a single search count as two.  And more often than not, I will switch to another tab or go to the next page.  There goes another set of "searches."

Comment: @Pekka's - Starting in the next build paging will also not count against the throttle, that should reduce the impact quite a bit.  Also, it's not sliding.  Once we change out some hardware and the IO cost isn't as big of a deal here we may increase it.

Comment: @Jeff - In the next build tabs/pages will *not* count, since that's not where the main (IO) cost is currently I've put a bit more handling in for that.

Comment: It would be REALLY helpful if the limit was relaxed for searches with no hits. Otherwise using standard search term refinement approaches will quickly run afoul of the limit.

Comment: I knew it was an expensive operation! http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135021/loophole-to-search-really-huge-queries